# How to select value in radiobuttonlist with protractor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, jasmine, protractor

I am trying to check a value in a radiobuttonlist:

```
<ul id="rbgHomeOccupier" class="radio-group cols-6">
            <li class="radio-group-button">
              <input type="radio" id="homeOccupierInjuredYes" class="radio-group-input" value="true"
                     tabindex="" name="homeOccupierInjured" ng-model="claim.damage.homeOccupierInjured" required>
              <label for="homeOccupierInjuredYes" class="radio-group-label">Yes</label>
            </li>
            <li class="radio-group-button">
              <input type="radio" id="homeOccupierInjuredNo" class="radio-group-input" value="false" tabindex=""
                     name="homeOccupierInjured"
                     ng-model="claim.damage.homeOccupierInjured" required>
              <label for="homeOccupierInjuredNo" class="radio-group-label">No</label>
            </li>
 </ul>
```

This is what I tried:

```
element.all(by.id('rbgHomeOccupier')).get(1).click();
```

However I get an error saying there is only one element:

```
 Failed: Index out of bound. Trying to access element at index: 1, but there are only 1 elements that match locator By.id("rbgHomeOccupier")
```

How can I select the 1st value ie 'Yes'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should perform `click()` action on the `input` elements and not on the list element. Moreover the element locator `by.id('rbgHomeOccupier')` is incorrect as there is only one element with that locator in the DOM and [`element.all()`](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder) tries to find all the elements in the DOM with that locator. Here's how to get the first radio input using [`get()`](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.get) function using proper locator and then click on it -

```
element.all(by.css('#rbgHomeOccupier input[type="radio"]')).get(0).click();
//Note: get() is a zero based index and so to click on the first element you need to pass 0 to the function
```

However there's an easy way if you have only one input element with id `homeOccupierInjuredYes` in the DOM. In this case you can call it directly without any need for `get()` function -

```
element(by.id('homeOccupierInjuredYes')).click();
```

Hope it helps.